# control visibility of fields per entity instance with WCF Data Service and Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework-4, wcf-data-services

As an example lets say we have a User entity with 10 fields that holds things like first name, last name, email, phone, ect. Four fields would be publicly visible and the remaining six would require an authorized subscription (two users are marked as friends for example).

When interrogating the dataservice in this manner: http://example.com/users?auth_token=xxx, the requester should only see the fields he has access to per user. This is much like how facebooks api works.

I went through all the trouble writing a custom data provider for WCF then realized it applies my rules over the whole collection. What I need is a rule-set per item in a collection. I had thought about writing hooks into WCF to morph the Message object passed back but I feel it may have too much overhead associated.

Anyone have an ideas on what could be done? Or even a different framework to settle my needs?

Answer (score 2):

This is sort of against the idea of WCF DS and OData. In OData you define a model (EDM) in which each entity has a certain set of properties. It is expected that all instances of that type have all those properties.
You can use open types (mark the entity type as open) to add additional properties which are optional (per instance), but then these won't be in the model.

Typically this is solved in one of two ways:

1) Split the entity into two entity types. The "public" one which everyone can see, and a "private" one which only authorized users can see. And have a navigation property between the public and private. In this case you can even hide the entire private entity from unauthorized users such that it won't be even visible in the model. (which is very secure and still completely defined in the model).

2) Use open types and properties and declared only the public properties and then populate the entity with the open properties only if the request is for authorized user. This doesn't "polute" the model with additional types, but it also means that the private properties are never declared in the model and thus users must know about them through other means (no codegen for these for example).

With custom provider you can also implement something else, custom providers can change the model per request. So in the unauthorized user case you only make the type have the public properties and in the authorized case you make the type have all the properties. But it then applies to all instances of that type in that one request (whether both #1 and #2 above let you do this on per instance bases if you really need to). This can be as secure as #1 and still statically typed, but it's more confusing since clients don't usually expect types to morph from request to request.

Comment: Thanks for your comments on this. It is what I feared would be. Not really a fan of either solutions as the code becomes convoluted. I want to keep EF clean so it can be used elsewhere. I suppose I will write a generic handler and use the template uri to match URLs.